# Find all permutations of numbers of exactly 9 characters long

Tags: python, permutation

I have the numbers `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16]`.

I want to find all permutations of numbers of exactly 9 characters. For example, if I have 8 single digit numbers, the last one can't be a double digit, because it would exceed the character limit.

Clarifications:

- The same number can be reused, so for example the number 1 nine times is valid.
- There can be any number of double digit numbers, as long as the total character length of the digits is exactly 9. For example, 1, 10, 12, 15, 16 is valid.

I tried `itertools.permutations`, but I couldn't get it to work with two-digit numbers.

Comment: So you also want combinations of numbers with less than 9 characters? That is, do you want `0` to be a valid combination? Or do you want *exactly* 9 characters?

Comment: I didn't understand what your task is. Can you show a few examples?

Comment: Can a number be reused?

Comment: If I understand your requirement properly, the only troublesome two digit number is 15, because the others are combinations of the valid 1 digit numbers.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think they mean that `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10` is a valid permutation, but `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 12` is not

Comment: Does this mean 1, 10, 12, 15, 16 is also a valid combination?

Comment: @mkrieger1 examples: 271001215

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yes

Comment: @Kraigolas i want exactly 9 characters

Comment: @Reti43 yes, its also valid

Comment: "I tried itertools.permutations, but I couldn't get it to work with two-digit numbers" Show us what you tried.

Comment: You said digits can be reused. Does this mean 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 is a valid combination? Also, can you clear up whether you're looking for combinations or permutations, i.e., is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 sufficient, or would you also want to have 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8 in there?

Comment: @JohnGordon it was a very simple code, I won't be able to remember exactly what I wrote there, but it was based on a code that matched letter combinations, it could produce 9 two-digit numbers and I didn't know how to fix it

Comment: @Reti43 yes it is valid combination. And yes, i would also want to have 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8. I think these are called permutations. English isn't my first language so i'm not sure :D,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a mixture of combination and permutations.

First find all of the combinations of the data which add up to the desired length. Then for each unique combination, find their permutations. There's probably some work to be done here which can limit the amount of incorrect combinations checked:

```
import itertools


def perm_of_length(data, length):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(data, i + 1):
            if sum(map(len, (map(str, comb)))) == length:
                for perm in itertools.permutations(comb):
                    yield perm


for perm in perm_of_length([0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 12], 4):
    print(perm)
```

Outputs:

```
(10, 12)
(12, 10)
(0, 1, 10)
(0, 10, 1)
(1, 0, 10)
(1, 10, 0)
(10, 0, 1)
(10, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 12)
(0, 12, 1)
(1, 0, 12)
(1, 12, 0)
(12, 0, 1)
(12, 1, 0)
(0, 2, 10)
(0, 10, 2)
(2, 0, 10)
(2, 10, 0)
(10, 0, 2)
(10, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 12)
(0, 12, 2)
(2, 0, 12)
(2, 12, 0)
(12, 0, 2)
(12, 2, 0)
(0, 3, 10)
(0, 10, 3)
(3, 0, 10)
(3, 10, 0)
(10, 0, 3)
(10, 3, 0)
(0, 3, 12)
(0, 12, 3)
(3, 0, 12)
(3, 12, 0)
(12, 0, 3)
(12, 3, 0)
(1, 2, 10)
(1, 10, 2)
(2, 1, 10)
(2, 10, 1)
(10, 1, 2)
(10, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 12)
(1, 12, 2)
(2, 1, 12)
(2, 12, 1)
(12, 1, 2)
(12, 2, 1)
(1, 3, 10)
(1, 10, 3)
(3, 1, 10)
(3, 10, 1)
(10, 1, 3)
(10, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 12)
(1, 12, 3)
(3, 1, 12)
(3, 12, 1)
(12, 1, 3)
(12, 3, 1)
(2, 3, 10)
(2, 10, 3)
(3, 2, 10)
(3, 10, 2)
(10, 2, 3)
(10, 3, 2)
(2, 3, 12)
(2, 12, 3)
(3, 2, 12)
(3, 12, 2)
(12, 2, 3)
(12, 3, 2)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 3, 2)
(0, 2, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 1, 2)
(0, 3, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 2, 3)
(1, 0, 3, 2)
(1, 2, 0, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 0, 2)
(1, 3, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 1, 3)
(2, 0, 3, 1)
(2, 1, 0, 3)
(2, 1, 3, 0)
(2, 3, 0, 1)
(2, 3, 1, 0)
(3, 0, 1, 2)
(3, 0, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 0, 2)
(3, 1, 2, 0)
(3, 2, 0, 1)
(3, 2, 1, 0)
```

Proof this works:

```
for perm in perm_of_length([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16], 9):
    assert sum(map(len, map(str, perm))) == 9
```

Comment: Seems to give the same results as my brute-force approach after changing the `==` to `<=`, but much faster.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq ah, interesting. Wasn't super sure how it would match up.

Comment: The OP stated in the comments that digits can be reused, so this seems to be missing a lot of solutions. But then he marked it as accepted, so I give up trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** this is much slower than it needs to be.

---

A simple, non-performant, brute-force approach with filtering:

```
symbols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16]
symbols = [str(x) for x in symbols]
perms = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    itertools.permutations(symbols, i) for i in range(10)
)
perms = ("".join(x) for x in perms)
perms = [x for x in perms if len(x) <= 9]

>>> len(perms)
13600046

>>> perms[:4]
['', '0', '1', '2']

>>> perms[-4:]
['987643102', '987643120', '987643201', '987643210']
```

One can drop the empty string by simply skipping the first item in `perms`.

---

A similar approach which does not use strings:

```
symbols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16]
lengths = {k: int(math.log10(k)) + 1 if k != 0 else 1 for k in symbols}
perms = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    itertools.permutations(symbols, i) for i in range(10)
)
perms = [x for x in perms if sum(lengths[k] for k in x) <= 9]

>>> len(perms)
13600046
```

---

If numbers can be reused (as mentioned in the comments), I would consider `itertools.product` instead of `itertools.permutations`:

```
symbols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16]
lengths = {k: int(math.log10(k)) + 1 if k != 0 else 1 for k in symbols}
perms = itertools.product(symbols, repeat=9)
perms = [x for x in perms if sum(lengths[k] for k in x) <= 9]
```